# Aumentar el ancho de una tabla Bootstrap-table al máximo de la página

Tags: css, bootstrap

Me gustaría poder aumentar el tamaño de la tabla a todo lo ancho de la página. Estoy utilizando bootstrap y bootstrap-table.

He intentado de definírselo en el fichero bootstrap-table dentro de `.fixed-table-container { width: 100% }` pero no funciona. ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Este es el código html y css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Web Testing</title>

    <!-- INCLUDES -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>

</head>

<body>          
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.es"><img src="assets/images/brandlogo.png"/></a></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active marges-opciones-right" ><a href="produccio.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px">work</i> Page1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li class="text-options marges-opciones-right"><a href="imatges.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px">collections</i> Page2</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown marges-opciones-left"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px" >face</i><span class="username"> Username </span><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px" >list</i></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><span class="glyphicon"></span><i class="material-icons">settings</i>  preferències</a></li>
                    <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><span class="glyphicon"></span><i class="material-icons">lock</i>  canviar password</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>   
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:18px">power_settings_new</i>  log out</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </nav>



        <!-- TABLE -->

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <h3 class="text-center">TITULO</h3><h5 class="text-center">SUBTITULO</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

           <div id="toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button id="changestatus" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#change'>BOTON 1</button>
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="row">
            <?php  
                    // Conexió a la base de dades
                    include("functions.php"); 
                    include("tools.php"); 
                    $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  
                    //query
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM test.registros ORDER BY id_articulo ASC";
                    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  
                    //se despliega el resultado  
                    echo "<table id='tableprod'
                                   data-toggle='table'
                                   data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                                   data-show-refresh='true'
                                   data-show-toggle='true'
                                   data-sort-name='name'
                                   data-sort-order='desc'
                                   data-show-columns='true'
                                   data-pagination='true'
                                   data-search='true'>";
                                   // data-click-to-select='true'>";
                        echo "<thead class='thead-inverse'>";
                            echo "<tr>";  
                                echo "<th data id='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>";
                                echo "<th data id='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>";   
                                echo "<th data id='campo1' data-sortable='true'>campo1</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='campo2' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>campo2</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='campo3' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>campo3</th>"; 
                                //echo "<th data id='image' data-switchable='false'>imatge</th>";   
                                echo "<th data id='campo4' data-sortable='true'>campo4</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='campo5' data-sortable='true'>campo5</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='campo6' data-sortable='true'>campo6</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='campo7' data-sortable='true'>campo7</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='campo8' data-sortable='true'>campo8</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='campo9' data-sortable='true'>campo9</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='campo10' data-sortable='true'>campo10</th>";
                                echo "<th data id='campo11' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>campo11</th>";
                                echo "<th data id='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>edit</th>";
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        echo "</thead>"; 
                        echo "<tbody>";
                    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){   
                            // echo $estado = EstadoColorRow($row[14]);  
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td></td>";
                                echo $estado = EstadoIcon($row[14]); 
                                echo "<td name='campo1'>$row[2]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td name='campo2'>$row[3]</td>";  
                                echo "<td name='campo3'>$row[4]</td>"; 
                                //echo $imatge = AddImage(); 
                                echo "<td name='campo4'>$row[5]</td>";
                                echo "<td name='campo5'>$row[6]</td>";  
                                echo "<td name='campo6'>$row[7]</td>";  
                                echo "<td name='campo7'>$row[8]</td>";  
                                echo "<td name='campo8'>$row[9]</td>";  
                                echo "<td name='campo9'>$row[10]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td name='campo10'>$row[11]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td name='campo11'>$row[12]</td>";
                                echo "<td>"?><p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs edit' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> </button></p></td>
                            </tr>  
                    <?php }  ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>  
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              Pie de página
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>


/**
 * @author zhixin wen <wenzhixin2010@gmail.com>
 * version: 1.11.0
 * https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/
 */

.bootstrap-table .table {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; */
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed),
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed) > tbody > tr > th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed) > tfoot > tr > th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed) > thead > tr > td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed) > tbody > tr > td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed) > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 8px;
}

.bootstrap-table .table.table-no-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.bootstrap-table .table.table-no-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
    /* border-right: 2px solid transparent; */
    border-right: 0;
}

.bootstrap-table .table.table-no-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.fixed-table-container {
    width: 100%
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
}

.fixed-table-container.table-no-bordered {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.fixed-table-footer,
.fixed-table-header {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed-table-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.fixed-table-body {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.fixed-table-container table {
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th:focus {
    outline: 0 solid transparent;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .th-inner,
.fixed-table-container tbody td .th-inner {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .sortable {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .both {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAQAAADYWf5HAAAAkElEQVQoz7X QMQ5AQBCF4dWQSJxC5wwax1Cq1e7BAdxD5SL+Tq/QCM1oNiJidwox0355mXnG/DrEtIQ6azioNZQxI0ykPhTQIwhCR+BmBYtlK7kLJYwWCcJA9M4qdrZrd8pPjZWPtOqdRQy320YSV17OatFC4euts6z39GYMKRPCTKY9UnPQ6P+GtMRfGtPnBCiqhAeJPmkqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .asc {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAAAZ0lEQVQ4y2NgGLKgquEuFxBPAGI2ahhWCsS/gDibUoO0gPgxEP8H4ttArEyuQYxAPBdqEAxPBImTY5gjEL9DM+wTENuQahAvEO9DMwiGdwAxOymGJQLxTyD+jgWDxCMZRsEoGAVoAADeemwtPcZI2wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .desc {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAAAZUlEQVQ4y2NgGAWjYBSggaqGu5FA/BOIv2PBIPFEUgxjB+IdQPwfC94HxLykus4GiD+hGfQOiB3J8SojEE9EM2wuSJzcsFMG4ttQgx4DsRalkZENxL+AuJQaMcsGxBOAmGvopk8AVz1sLZgg0bsAAAAASUVORK5CYII= ');
}

.fixed-table-container th.detail {
    width: 30px;
}

.fixed-table-container tbody td {
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.fixed-table-container tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
}

.fixed-table-container tbody td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

/* the same color with .active */
.fixed-table-container tbody .selected td {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.fixed-table-container .bs-checkbox {
    text-align: center;
}

.fixed-table-container .bs-checkbox .th-inner {
    padding: 8px 0;
}

.fixed-table-container input[type="radio"],
.fixed-table-container input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.fixed-table-container .no-records-found {
    text-align: center;
}

.fixed-table-pagination div.pagination,
.fixed-table-pagination .pagination-detail {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fixed-table-pagination div.pagination .pagination {
    margin: 0;
}

.fixed-table-pagination .pagination a {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
}

.fixed-table-pagination .pagination-info {
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.fixed-table-pagination .btn-group {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.fixed-table-pagination .dropup .dropdown-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fixed-table-pagination .page-list {
    display: inline-block;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .columns-left {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .columns-right {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .columns label {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .bs-bars,
.fixed-table-toolbar .search,
.fixed-table-toolbar .columns {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.fixed-table-pagination li.disabled a {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.fixed-table-loading {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.fixed-table-body .card-view .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 30%;
    text-align: left !important;
}

/* support bootstrap 2 */
.fixed-table-body thead th .th-inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table th, .table td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .dropdown-menu {
    text-align: left;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .btn-group > .btn-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1px !important;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .btn-group > .btn-group > .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .btn-group > .btn-group:first-child > .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .btn-group > .btn-group:last-child > .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.bootstrap-table .table > thead > tr > th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

/* support bootstrap 3 */
.bootstrap-table .table thead > tr > th {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-footer tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-footer .table {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.pull-right .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}

/* calculate scrollbar width */
p.fixed-table-scroll-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

div.fixed-table-scroll-outer {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Aparte de esto tengo aplicado el fichero css de bootstrap. Si es necesario pasaría el código pero está con las opciones por defecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a poner la tabla dentro de un

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <!-- tu tabla aquí siempre se verá al 100% en todas las resolcuiones-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Los elementos de Bootstrap se adaptan al ancho que tienen sus contenedores por lo que si está dentro de un **container-fluid** este a su vez en un **col-md-12** este será del 100% de la página, y si metes la tabla dentro de un col-md-6 por ejemplo, esta será del 50% de la página

Comment: Eso es gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar dos cosas:

1. Cargar el fichero bootstrap, primero y luego el fichero tuyo
2. Probar a definir el contenedor dentro del row, que sería algo así

   ```
           <?php  
                   // Conexió a la base de dades
                   include("functions.php"); 
                   include("tools.php"); 
                   $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  
                   //query
                   $query = "SELECT * FROM test.registros ORDER BY id_articulo ASC";
                   $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  
                   //se despliega el resultado  
                   echo "<table id='tableprod'
                                  data-toggle='table'
                                  data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                                  data-show-refresh='true'
                                  data-show-toggle='true'
                                  data-sort-name='name'
                                  data-sort-order='desc'
                                  data-show-columns='true'
                                  data-pagination='true'
                                  data-search='true'>";
                                  // data-click-to-select='true'>";
                       echo "<thead class='thead-inverse'>";
                           echo "<tr>";  
                               echo "<th data id='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>";
                               echo "<th data id='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>";   
                               echo "<th data id='campo1' data-sortable='true'>campo1</th>";  
                               echo "<th data id='campo2' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>campo2</th>";  
                               echo "<th data id='campo3' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>campo3</th>"; 
                               //echo "<th data id='image' data-switchable='false'>imatge</th>";   
                               echo "<th data id='campo4' data-sortable='true'>campo4</th>"; 
                               echo "<th data id='campo5' data-sortable='true'>campo5</th>"; 
                               echo "<th data id='campo6' data-sortable='true'>campo6</th>"; 
                               echo "<th data id='campo7' data-sortable='true'>campo7</th>"; 
                               echo "<th data id='campo8' data-sortable='true'>campo8</th>"; 
                               echo "<th data id='campo9' data-sortable='true'>campo9</th>";  
                               echo "<th data id='campo10' data-sortable='true'>campo10</th>";
                               echo "<th data id='campo11' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>campo11</th>";
                               echo "<th data id='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>edit</th>";
                           echo "</tr>"; 
                       echo "</thead>"; 
                       echo "<tbody>";
                   while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){   
                           // echo $estado = EstadoColorRow($row[14]);  
                           echo "<tr>";
                               echo "<td></td>";
                               echo $estado = EstadoIcon($row[14]); 
                               echo "<td name='campo1'>$row[2]</td>"; 
                               echo "<td name='campo2'>$row[3]</td>";  
                               echo "<td name='campo3'>$row[4]</td>"; 
                               //echo $imatge = AddImage(); 
                               echo "<td name='campo4'>$row[5]</td>";
                               echo "<td name='campo5'>$row[6]</td>";  
                               echo "<td name='campo6'>$row[7]</td>";  
                               echo "<td name='campo7'>$row[8]</td>";  
                               echo "<td name='campo8'>$row[9]</td>";  
                               echo "<td name='campo9'>$row[10]</td>"; 
                               echo "<td name='campo10'>$row[11]</td>"; 
                               echo "<td name='campo11'>$row[12]</td>";
                               echo "<td>"?><p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs edit' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> </button></p></td>
                           </tr>  
                   <?php }  ?>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>  
      </div>
   ```

Comment: Voy a probar, gracias!

Comment: Has introducido la tabla dentro de un **container-fluid** ? normalmente los contenidos se adaptan al ancho del recipiente donde se encuentran